# Examine the convergence of a sequence ${a_{n}}$: $a_{n+1}=a_{n}-\sin(a_{n}),0\le a_{1}<\pi$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

${a_{n}}$: $a_{n+1}=a_{n}-\sin(a_{n}),0\le a_{1}<\pi$

One way to do it is to show that the sequence is bounded and monotonous.

How to show that it is bounded?

If

$$-1\le \sin(a_{n})\le 1$$

then

$$0\le a_{n}<2\pi$$

Is it right that then

$$0\le a_{n+1}\le 2\pi$$

and the sequence is bounded (below and above)?

From

$$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=a_{n}-\sin(a_{n})-a_{n}=-\sin(a_{n}),a_{n}\in[0,2\pi]$$

the sequence is monotonous and non-increasing.

Can someone check this problem?

Comment: For positive $x$ it's true: $\sin x < x$, and therefore $\forall n\enspace a_n > 0$. $a_{n+1}-a_n = -\sin a_n < 0$ (because $a_0 < \pi$, $a_1 < a_0$ and so on; you may use induction). It decreasing and it's lower bound is 0; therefore, $a_n$ has a limit.

Answer (score 1):

Your first implication does not hold. A counterexample would be $a_n=100$. Its sine is certainly between $-1$ and $1$, but $100$ itself is not between $0$ and $2\pi$.

I think it would be easier to say that if $a_n\in[0,\pi]$ then $a_{n+1}\in[0,\pi]$ because $0\le\sin x\le x$ when $x\in[0,\pi]$. Then, by induction, every $a_n$ is in this interval.

It is also *true* that if $a_n\in[0,2\pi)$ then $a_{n+1}\in[0,2\pi)$, but on one hand it is *more work* to argue that (because $\sin a_n$ can then be both positive or negative), and on the other hand it *doesn't tell you enough* that you can argue that the sequence is monotonic. For that you need to know that the $a_n$s *stay* within the range where the sine is nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved in a more generic manner.

Let $g(x) = x - \sin(x)$. The key observation is

- $g'(x) = 1 - \cos x \ge 0 $ for all $x$, so $g(x)$ is increasing over whole $\mathbb{R}$.
- $g'(x) = 0$ at and only at isolated points $2n\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$,
  this implies $g(x)$ is strictly increasing.

In other words, $g$ is order preserving!

Start from any real number $b$, one can construct a sequence $( b_n )_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ by 
$$b_n = \begin{cases} b, & n = 1\\ g(b_{n-1}), & n > 1\end{cases}$$
There are three possibilities:

1. $b_2 = g(b_1) = b$ : we will have $b_n = b$ for all $n$.
2. $b_2 = g(b_1) > b$ : we will have 
   $$b_2 > b_1 \implies b_3 = g(b_2) > g(b_1) = b_2 \implies b_4 > b_3 \implies \ldots$$
   i.e. $b_n$ will be an increasing sequence.
3. $b_2 = g(b_1) < b$ : we will have
   $$b_2 < b_1 \implies b_3 = g(b_2) < g(b_1) = b_2 \implies b_4 < b_3 \implies 
   \ldots$$
   i.e. $b_n$ will be an decreasing sequence.

Furthermore, if $m, M$ are any pair of successive fixed points of $g(x)$, then
for any $b \in (m, M)$, 
$$ m < b_1 < M \implies m = g(m) < b_2 = g_(b_2) < M = g(M)\\ \implies
m < b_3 < M \implies m < b_4 < M \implies \ldots$$
i.e. the whole sequences $b_n$ will falls inside $(m,M)$. Being a bounded monotonic sequence, $b_n$ will converge to some numbers $b_\infty \in [m,M]$. Since $g(x)$ is continuous, $g(b_\infty) = b_\infty$. This implies $b_\infty \ne (m,M)$ and hence $b_\infty = m$ or $M$.

For those cases where $g(x)$

- has a largest fixed points $m'$ and $b$ falls between $(m',\infty)$
- or a smallest fixed points $M'$ and $b$ falls between $(-\infty,M')$,

the analysis will be similar. In general, we will have

$$b_{\infty} \stackrel{def}{=} \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \begin{cases} 
+\infty,& \text{ if } g(b) > b, b \in (m', \infty)\\
m',& \text{ if } g(b) < b, b \in (m', \infty)\\
M,& \text{ if } g(b) > b, b \in (m, M)\\
m,& \text{ if } g(b) < b, b \in (m, M)\\
M',& \text{ if } g(b) > b, b \in (-\infty,M')\\
-\infty,& \text{ if } g(b) < b, b \in (-\infty, M')
\end{cases}
$$

Apply this to our function $g(x) = x - \sin(x)$. Notice the fixed points of our $g(x)$ are located at $n\pi$ with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Over the two successive fixed points $0$ and $\pi$,
$$g(x) = x - \sin(x) < x, \quad\text{ for } x \in (0,\pi)$$

By above argument, we find $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.

As one can see, what we really need from $g(x)$ is the properties that it is continuous and strictly increasing. If you generate a sequence by functional iteration of a strictly increasing continuous function, the sequences converges
to either one of its nearby fixed points or $\pm \infty$. Which fixed point
to converge is controlled by the sign of $b_2 - b_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It suffices to show $0 \leq \sin a_n < a_n$ for $a_n$ in your range between $0$ and $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the sine of *any* number is in $[-1,1]$, not only of numbers in $[0,2\pi)$. But that does not interest us.

To show this is monotonic, we will show that $\sin(a_n)\geq0$ for all $n$. For $a_1$, this is easy, since the sine is positive in $[0,\pi]$. $a_2$ is still in that interval since it is bounded by $a_1-0$ and $a_1-1$ which are both there. So $\sin(a_2)\geq0$. If $a_n\in[0,\pi]$ for all $n$, we are done. But it is easy to show $x-\sin x\geq0$ for $x\geq0$, since if you draw a unit circle and choose a point at angle $x$ from the positive $x$-axis, the $y$ of that point is $\sin x$ and the arc is $x$ in length since the radius is 1, and the arc is clearly longer than the segment. This proves our claim for $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, and after that $x\geq\frac{\pi}{2}>1\geq\sin x$. This means our sequence is bounded by 0, and therefore cannot ever escape $[0,\pi]$, thus the sines are all positive, and the sequence is monotonic nonincreasing.

While proving monotony, we found a lower bound, 0.

Lower bound plus nonincreasing monotony implies convergence, thus $a_n$ converges to some limit, probably 0.